# DATE_SUB & DATE_ADD mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a requirement wherein email notification should be sent via a workflow in each of the following three cases,

1. 2 months prior to 6 month probation end from start date
2. 3 weeks prior to 6 month probation end from start date
3. 1 week prior to 6 month probation end from start date

I am using the below query to get the start dates that will fulfill mentioned criteria for testing purposes.

```
SELECT 
    CURDATE(),
    DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH),
        INTERVAL 2 MONTH) 2monthStartDate,
    DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH),
        INTERVAL 3 WEEK) threeweekStartDate,
    DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH),
        INTERVAL 1 WEEK) OneweekStartDate,
    DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD('2021-10-16', INTERVAL 6 MONTH),
        INTERVAL 2 MONTH) notificationDate6Month,
    DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD('2021-09-06', INTERVAL 6 MONTH),
        INTERVAL 3 WEEK) notificationDate3Week,
    DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD('2021-08-23', INTERVAL 6 MONTH),
        INTERVAL 1 WEEK) notificationDate1Week
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=884cfd4b5cd68ffe0d1dc32da6673752)

The start dates i am getting do fulfill the criteria,though for the three week period the query returns a start date of 2021-09-06 *threeweekStartDate*, though this returns 2022-02-13 on *notificationDate3Week*. I cannot make out why. A start date of 2021-09-09 does return 2022-02-16. Why the three day difference ?

Comment: Do not use DATE_ADD/DATE_SUB. Use direct INTERVAL add/substract - it is  more clear. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fef6c31ce69279cfe831335f2813ae9

Comment: Ok. But i am sure you noticed the results are the same for both queries, specifically for the three week start date.

Comment: You tell about `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH + INTERVAL 3 WEEK threeweekStartDate` which is 2021-09-06? Current date is 2022-02-16. 6 months before is 2021-08-16. 3 weeks after this is 2021-08-(16+3*7) -> 2021-08-37 -> 2021-(08+1)-(37-31) -> 2021-09-06. What is wrong?

Comment: Why is *'2021-09-06' + INTERVAL 6 MONTH - INTERVAL 3 WEEK notificationDate3Week* returning 2022-02-13. I am expecting it to return 2022-02-16

Comment: 2021-09-06 + 6 months -> 2021-(09+6)-06 -> 2021-15-06 -> (2021+1)-(15-12)-(06) -> 2022-03-06. Then 2022-03-06 - 3 week -> 2022-03-(06-3*7) -> 2022-03-(-15) -> 2022-(03-1)-(-15+28) -> 2022-02-13. February in 2022 is 28 days long.

Comment: *I am expecting it to return 2022-02-16* Reason? show your calculations which produces this value... maybe you confuse the date changes ordering? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3acac2c8517aa1c62e18b8ad2d213650